# SEO - correct way to redirect 301 for crawler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, seo, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with Google's crawling and I am not sure if its a technical problem. Basically we redesigned our site a bit so we 301-redirect users like this:

url.com/ --> url.com/en/items  or
url.com/en --> url.com/en/items

So every user ends up at the page url.com/lang/items

As recommended we use

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang=
```

to tell Google where to find the shown page in another language.
eg:
http://www.url.com/en/boats has the tag:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="http://www.url.com/de/boote" />
```

and on http://www.url.com/de/boote its:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="http://www.url.com/en/boats" />
```

Now, the crawler gives us the crawl errors "No backlinks" for **url.com/en** and **url.com/de/items**. Of course **url.com/de/items** links back to **url.com/en/items**, since **url.com/en** does not exist anymore. Why is the page **url.com/en** even considered here?

I redirect like this:

```
Response.Redirect(site);
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.End();
```

Any hint greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

with theses information its hard to say, if something is maybe missconfigured. 
Could you pleaese add the exact lines of code for the  tags for both pages?

Did you add also the line for the page itself, described in this article https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag . This was an issue we had while implementing the hreflangs, and we got exactly the same errors.

It could also be that the google crawler has not yet indexed the "new" sites with the new urls, so it has still the old urls indexed. This could take a bit time, mentioned in this discussion https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-Google-recognize-301-redirect-updates-and-remove-the-old-pages-from-its-index

Comment: thanks for the reply, made an edit to the post. But I think the problem is with the redirect. for all other pages, no error is shown. The redirect-pages seem to be the problem. As said for example url.com/en does not exist anymore, but Google still requires a back link to it ?!

Comment: If I understand you correct, you have a bunch pages with configured hreflang attributes, which are fine, and not throwing errors in google. And only the ones with the 301 implemented redirect, are not correct? If so i would suggest to test your redirect e.g. with this tool http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php this helped us to check how our redirects or status codes are seen from outside.

Comment: thanks for the tool! But it says everything is fine. The redirect seems to be configured correctly. url.com is correctly redirected with 301 to url.com/en/boats. The only question is, why does Google say, I need a backlink from url.com/en/boats to url.com. That doesnt make sense at all, if you keep in mind that url.com "does not exist", it only checks for the user language and redirects...